# Why is an explicit cast not needed here?

Tags: java, methods, casting, return-type

```
class MyClass {
    void myMethod(byte b) {
        System.out.print("myMethod1");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        MyClass me = new MyClass();
        me.myMethod(12);
    }
}
```

I understand that the argument of `myMethod()` being an `int` literal, and the parameter `b` being of type byte, this code would generate a compile time error. (which could be avoided by using an explicit byte cast for the argument: `myMethod((byte)12)` )

```
class MyClass{
    byte myMethod() {
        return 12;
    }

    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        MyClass me = new MyClass();
        me.myMethod();
    }
}
```

After experiencing this, I expected that the above code too would generate a compile time error, considering that 12 is an `int` literal and the return type of `myMethod()` is byte. But no such error occurs. (No explicit cast is needed: `return (byte)12;` )

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java supports narrowing in this case. From the [Java Language Spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2-300-A) on *Assignment Conversion*:

> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>   variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant
>   expression is representable in the type of the variable.

Comment: I think this is the right answer, so +1. moonwave99's answer is not correct.

Comment: @McDowell but why isn't this narrowing primitive conversion applied when passing the `int` literal 12 as a parameter expecting a `byte` argument?

Comment: @jlordo - This rule applies to variable assignment. The Language specification does not require narrowing when passing a literal as a parameter. _As to why the specification has this limitation, you'd have to ask James Gosling._ I've clarified my answer.

Comment: Thanks McDowell. Thank you for the link for "narrowing". I'd never heard of it before. +1.

Answer (score 2):

From [Java Primitive Data Type reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127 (inclusive).

Try returning 128 : ))

Comment: I already have, but my point is returning a value between -127 to +128 SHOULD generate an error.

Comment: @moonwave99 so is there an implicit cast, because the return type of the method is byte? If so, why isn't that also applied to the passing of the parameter in OPs first code example?

Comment: A `byte`is a "constrained" `int`, [e.g. like `short`]. There is no need for raising an error at all.

Comment: jlordo got my point. QUOTE: why isn't that also applied to the passing of the parameter in OPs first code example?

Comment: @Prashan well now I got a better clue on the question - I don't actually know what Java does in this sense, the behaviour seems inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

This will work `byte b = 4` as long as value is within the range, but if you try something like `byte b = 2000` you would get compiler error because it is out of range. `12` is in within range so you aren't getting error.

Comment: But 12 is an int literal, I'm trying to return an int literal. It doesn't matter whether it's inside the range of byte or not. That's why the first code fragment generated an error.